Query SwiftUI with SwiftData, change picker dynamically
I am trying to create two Pickers, one dependent on the other.
Both come from two SwiftData models Ruta and Parada.
But I don't manage to paint the second one, if I try to binding the variable Parada, I get an error.


import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct FormFavouritesTestView: View {
    
    @State var loadData: ReadDataModel?
    @State var idRutaNuevo:String = "1"
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var paradas: [Parada]
    @State private var selectedParada: Parada?
    
    @Query var queryRutas:[Ruta]
    
    @Query(sort: \Ruta.idRuta) private var rutas: [Ruta]
    @State private var selectedRuta: Ruta?

    
    private func cargar(){
        loadData = ReadDataModel(modelContext: modelContext)
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                
                Section(
                    header: Text("Dirección y parada")
                ){
                    
                    Picker(selection: $selectedRuta, label: Text("Dirección")) {
                        Text("Selecciona")
                        ForEach(rutas) { ruta in
                            Text(ruta.idRuta + " - " + ruta.name)
                                .tag(Optional(ruta))
                        }
                    }.onChange(of: selectedRuta){
                        print(selectedRuta!.idRuta)
                        if selectedRuta!.idRuta == "1" {
                            idRutaNuevo = "2"
                        }else{
                            idRutaNuevo = "1"
                        }
                        
                    }
                  
                    PickerParadasView(selectedParada: $selectedParada, idRutaNuevo: $idRutaNuevo)
                    
                    
                    Button("Done") {
                        print("La  dirección \(idRutaNuevo)")
                    }
                    
                }
                
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Nueva Ruta")

        }
        .onAppear(){
            
            cargar()
            
            selectedRuta = queryRutas.first
            if let rutaAux = selectedRuta {
                idRutaNuevo = rutaAux.idRuta
                print("Entro aquí \(rutaAux.idRuta)")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct PickerParadasView:View {
    
    @Binding private var paradas: [Parada]
    
    @Binding var selectedParada: Parada?
    @Binding var idRutaNuevo:String
    

    
    init(){
        
        let predicate = #Predicate<Parada> {
            $0.idRuta == "2"
        }
        $paradas = Query(filter: predicate, sort: \.id)
         
    }
    
    
    var body: some View{
        
        Picker(selection: $selectedParada, label: Text("Parada")) {
                ForEach(paradas) { parada in
                    Text("\(parada.id) - " + parada.title)
                        .tag(Optional(parada))
                }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    FormFavouritesTestView()
        .modelContainer(for: [Parada.self, Ruta.self, Favorito.self], inMemory: true)
}



I need Parada to be filtered by [RUTA].idRoute and sorted by Parada.id.
Someone can help me?
Thank you in advanced!

Instead of onChange try a computed binding for the picker

Note NavigationView is deprecated, use NavigationStack instead.
